# EDIT: ES6 : rolling and testing my own PRNG hash hex key generator?

Tags: algorithm, random, ecmascript-6

[EDIT: post was originnaly too long... trying to shorten it !]

for building some VNodes based app, I need a function that can generate pseudo random numbers, used as unique IDs, with a 3 or 4 bytes sizes.

Think a random RGB or RBBA, CSS-like string colors like : 'bada55' or '900dcafe'... User could seed the generator by picking a random pixel in a PNG image, for example.

Due to functionnal aspects of my app, generator must a pure function avpoding side effects like : using Math.random...

I'm not aware of artithmetic theories (my courses are so far in past...) but I decided to roll a custom PRNG, using Multiply-With-Carry (MWC) paradigm, and test it empirically with some prime coeffs, and random colors seeds.

My idea is to test it with 1-byte, 2-bytes, 3-bytes, and then 4-bytes outputs : my feelings are :

- identifiying "good" primes and potential 'bad' seeds when number of bytes is lower
- and try to test it against a cresing number of bytes

[EDITED FROM HERE]

MCW usually works as follow:

```
# each turn, compute the i-th byte:
  Xi[i] = A * Zi[i] + Ci[i]
  Ci[i] = Math.floor((A * Zi[i] + Ci[i]) /  M)
  Zi[i] = Xi[i] % M
```

where A is the multiplier, C the increment and M the modulus. For bytes the modulus is 256.

It's possible to determine mathematically A and C (prime numbers) to get a full cycle generator.

The trouble is that, when a byte cell starts to loop to its seed value, ALL cells do that... so the period is 256 for 4 bytes !

I need to build something like an odometer to shift values of othrt cells and garantuee a priod of Math.pow(256, 4).

How to achieve that in a simple way, if possible ?

Comment: "*performances seems to be poor*" - when running what code exactly? How did you measure performance? Did you compare it against a different implementation? Did you use a profiler?

Comment: Very poor, I computed A = list of 100 first primes, and C (the same)... looping in A *C, selectong a random rgba color with Math.random() and seeding the generator createMWC's constructor, and calling next() until collisions, old empirical method... and holding stat = { min, max } for each <a, c> entry. 
With 1 byte, loops in 151 turns, and with 4 only 3 !!!

I'll trying to figure what's happening, the MCW idea sounded good at beginning, but now... desesprating !

Comment: Have you tried asking the question at code review?

Comment: just seeking a path to find good coefficeints !

Comment: performance incresaed significally... but wikipedia entry for MWC asserts that a "full cycle" could be impossible, and 0's value are forbidden --> need to rebase the generator with M = 257, A = 197 and C = 231... plotting {x, y} = { U[i], U[i+1] } seems to give expected behavior ! sounds better !